# getElementById not receiving input properly/not displaying - javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a calculator that is supposed to display totals after parsing variables that collected user input in previous functions. However, only 1/3 of the boxes meant for displaying the totals actually display a value, the other two stay blank. The one that works is "DisplayTotalAssets".

I'm not sure what exactly is causing the issue. I'm using `.getElementById` in a readonly text box to display the totals after making some calculations. I tried looking up if there was an issue with using multiple `.getElementById` so close together but I don't have any experience with interference. Before, I thought calling multiple functions when using `oninput` was the problem, but I checked syntax and it seems to be correct.

Edited to be reproducible. If something seems like a weird way of doing it, it might be because I cut out so much of the other extra stuff that is in my full program.

```js
var LiquidTotal;
var InvestTotal;
var CurrentTotal;
var LoansTotal;
var TotalAssets;
var TotalLiables;
var NetWorth;

function ValidNum(n) {
  n = n.replace(/\-/g, '');
  n = n.replace(/\,/g, '');
  n = n.replace(/\$/g, '');

  if (!isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n)) {
    return parseFloat(n).toFixed(2);
  } else {
    return parseFloat(0.00).toFixed(2);
  }
}

function LiquidMath() {
  var a = ValidNum(document.getElementById("cash").value);

  a = parseFloat(a);

  LiquidTotal = a;

  if (isNaN(LiquidTotal)) {
    return false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("DisplayLiquidTotal").value = '$' + parseFloat(LiquidTotal).toFixed(2);
  }

  return document.getElementById("LiquidTotal").value;
}

function InvestMath() {
  var a = ValidNum(document.getElementById("stocks").value);

  a = parseFloat(a);

  InvestTotal = a;

  if (isNaN(InvestTotal)) {
    return false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("DisplayInvestTotal").value = '$' + parseFloat(InvestTotal).toFixed(2);
  }

  return document.getElementById("InvestTotal").value;
}

function CurrentMath() {
  var a = ValidNum(document.getElementById("utilities").value);

  a = parseFloat(a);

  CurrentTotal = a;

  if (isNaN(CurrentTotal)) {
    return false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("DisplayCurrentTotal").value = '$' + parseFloat(CurrentTotal).toFixed(2);
  }

  return document.getElementById("CurrentTotal").value;
}

function LoansMath() {
  var a = ValidNum(document.getElementById("education").value);

  a = parseFloat(a);

  LoansTotal = a;

  if (isNaN(LoansTotal)) {
    return false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("DisplayLoansTotal").value = '$' + parseFloat(LoansTotal).toFixed(2);
  }

  return document.getElementById("LoansTotal").value;
}

function AssetsTotal() {
  TotalAssets = LiquidTotal + InvestTotal;

  if (isNaN(TotalAssets)) {
    return false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("DisplayTotalAssets").value = '$' + parseFloat(TotalAssets).toFixed(2);
  }

  return document.getElementById("TotalAssets").value;
}

function LiablesTotal() {
  TotalLiables = CurrentTotal + LoansTotal;

  if (isNaN(TotalLiables)) {
    return false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("DisplayTotalLiables").value = '$' + parseFloat(TotalLiables).toFixed(2);
  }

  return document.getElementById("TotalLiables").value;
}

function GrandTotal() {
  NetWorth = TotalAssets - TotalLiables;

  if (isNaN(NetWorth)) {
    return false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("DisplayNetWorth").value = '$' + parseFloat(NetWorth).toFixed(2);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="assets" class="col-xs-6">
  <h3>Assets</h3>
  <h4>Liquid Assets</h4>
  <div class="row" style="padding:1px;">
    <div class="col-xs-8">Cash On Hand: <input type="text" id="cash" onblur="LiquidMath()" oninput="AssetsTotal(); LiablesTotal(); GrandTotal();" class="form-control" maxlength="30" style="background-color: #FFFFE0;" /></div>
    <div class="col-xs-8">Total: <input type="text" id="DisplayLiquidTotal" onblur="LiquidMath()" readonly="readonly" class="form-control" maxlength="30" style="background-color: #FFFFE0;" /></div>
  </div>

  <h4>Investments</h4>
  <div class="row" style="padding:1px;">
    <div class="col-xs-8">Stocks: <input type="number" id="stocks" onblur="InvestMath()" oninput="AssetsTotal(); LiablesTotal(); GrandTotal();" class="form-control" maxlength="30" style="background-color: #FFFFE0;" /></div>
    <div class="col-xs-8">Total: <input type="text" id="DisplayInvestTotal" onblur="InvestMath()" readonly="readonly" class="form-control" maxlength="30" style="background-color: #FFFFE0;" /></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="liables" class="col-xs-6">
  <h3>Liabilities</h3>
  <h4>Current Liabilities (due within 1 month)</h4>
  <div class="row" style="padding:1px;">
    <div class="col-xs-8">Utilities: <input type="number" id="utilities" onblur="CurrentMath()" oninput="AssetsTotal(); LiablesTotal(); GrandTotal();" class="form-control" maxlength="30" style="background-color: #FFFFE0;" /></div>
    <div class="col-xs-8">Total: <input type="text" id="DisplayCurrentTotal" onblur="CurrentMath()" readonly="readonly" class="form-control" maxlength="30" style="background-color: #FFFFE0;" /></div>
  </div>

  <h4>Long-Term Liabilities</h4>
  <div class="row" style="padding:1px;">
    <div class="col-xs-8">Education Loans: <input type="text" id="education" onblur="LoansMath()" oninput="AssetsTotal(); LiablesTotal(); GrandTotal();" class="form-control" maxlength="30" style="background-color: #FFFFE0;" /></div>
    <div class="col-xs-8">Total: <input type="text" id="DisplayLoansTotal" onblur="LoansMath()" readonly="readonly" class="form-control" maxlength="30" style="background-color: #FFFFE0;" /></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row" style="padding:1px;">
  <div class="col-xs-8">
    <div class="col-xs-8">
      <h4>Total Assets:</h4> <input type="text" id="DisplayTotalAssets" readonly="readonly" class="form-control" maxlength="30" style="background-color: #FFFFE0;" /></div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-8">
    <div class="col-xs-8">
      <h4>Total Liabilities:</h4> <input type="text" id="DisplayTotalLiables" readonly="readonly" class="form-control" maxlength="30" style="background-color: #FFFFE0;" /></div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-8">
    <div class="col-xs-8">
      <h4>Net Worth:</h4> <input type="text" id="DisplayNetWorth" readonly="readonly" class="form-control" maxlength="30" style="background-color: #FFFFE0;" /></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Any errors in the console? How do you call your functions?

Comment: If you are having more than one dom elements with same id, the `document.getElementById` returns the first one from dom tree it can find.

Comment: Please create a [mcve] so we can see the issue on the question. But it looks like a problem with repeated id's as HasilT mentions above.

Comment: @HasilT I've given all of elements that receive input or display information unique IDs, does it have to do with the fact that the output text box is a div inside of another div?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro edited, apologies for any wasted time

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic because the problem is caused by a typo. The ID you are searching for doesn't match the ID of any element.

Comment: @Quentin the issue I'm having is with the bottom three text boxes, IDs are "DisplayTotalAssets", "DisplayTotalLiables", and "DisplayNetWorth". Where is the typo in either the HTML or JS?

Comment: @JakeLong — Open the developer tools in your browser. Go to the console. Run your code. Type something into the first input. Press tab. Look at the error message in the console. Click the line number to the right of the error message. It will take you straight to it.

Comment: You're looking at the wrong thing. LiquidTotal, InvestTotal, etc.

Comment: @GalacticCowboy So is the problem using `document.getElementById().value`? The console gives me the "cannot read property value of null" error with `.value` in red underline. I get the error every time I type in any of the text boxes, too. I understand that the error basically says that the element doesn't exist, but I can't find why.

Comment: You were trying to access id values that did not exist, so getElementById() returned null.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed both the console errors and the entire original issue by changing the return statement in all of the functions

```
else
   {
    return document.getElementById("DisplayLiquidTotal").value = '$' + parseFloat(LiquidTotal).toFixed(2);
   }
```